How to Remove Inactive Bluetooth Peripherals from a Table in Swift Using CoreBluetooth?
I’m working on a Swift application using CoreBluetooth, and I’m facing an issue with managing discovered peripherals. In the didDiscoverPeripheral delegate method, I discover peripherals and add them to a Set to avoid duplicates. However, when a peripheral is turned off or goes out of range, it remains in the Set, causing it to still appear in my UITableView.
I want to implement functionality similar to what you see in the system Bluetooth settings, where inactive or deactivated devices are automatically removed from the list.
What’s the best approach to dynamically remove inactive peripherals from my Set and update my UITableView accordingly? Should I rely on peripheral state updates or is there a more effective strategy?

Short answer: pass CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey to your scanForPeripherals call. This will cause you to get a callback every time an advertising packet is seen from the device while your app is in the foreground (this is ignored in the background).
You will then have to decide how many seconds of not seeing an advertising packet until you consider it "gone." What is reasonable highly depends on the devices, but around 10 seconds will probably work for most use cases, and 30 seconds is quite safe. For certain use cases with known device types, timeouts of 2-3 seconds may work well. You will need to experiment a bit.
Many central-side things can impact scanning performance dramatically as well, such as whether WiFi is in use at the same time, how many BLE devices are in range, and how many BLE connections the central is managing.
Note that Apple claims this option reduces the phone's battery life somewhat (though doesn't really explain to how great an extent), so it isn't recommended unless it's important for your use case. But it is there if you need it.

Now, let's discuss some of the nuance of this answer, and why there is no deterministic way to do this.
It's important to separate what you see in settings, which is almost entirely BR/EDR Bluetooth (anything with an (i) beside it), from what you're searching for, which is Bluetooth Low-Energy. They have some slight similarities, but they're pretty different things. In particular, the "Low-Energy" part is important, because some choices are made to reduce power utilization. The right thing to compare to is another BLE app like nRF Connect.
The key thing to know about BLE discovery is that it's based on the following system. (There are several other things going on at the same time, and I'm simplifying a lot of things, but this is the key part of discovery.)
The peripheral is in a loop that sends a packet, waits, switches channels, and then repeats on that new channel.
The central (your phone) is in a loop that listens for a packet for a while, switches channels, and then repeats on that new channel.
It is possible that two peripherals advertise on the same channel at the same time, in which case they may interfere.
There are 3 primary advertising channels (we'll ignore secondary advertising for the moment).
This is all important because depending on the timing, it can take quite a while (at least several seconds) for the central to be listening at the same time that the peripheral is advertising, on the same channel, and with a low enough error rate for the central to actually see the peripheral. Some devices advertise extremely slowly (as slow as once every two seconds), so discovering them can take a very long time. Most advertising packets are not heard.
So at any given time, failing to see a peripheral does not tell you much about whether it's still out there. You usually cannot see a given peripheral. It's a miracle you ever see a peripheral. (But it is this miracle that we rely on.)
Once you connect to a device, the two sides synchronize their channel hopping to make the connection more robust. And packets are sent much more often, so it's easier (but still not trivial) to determine if the other side has disappeared.

First of all, thank you for your detailed comment.
When I start my application I scan for BLE devices without using the CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey option. However, on the screen where the user needs to pair the device, I would like it to continuously see the devices and prevent them from interacting with a device in case they "gone".
The best approach in this scenario seems to be to restart the scan with CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey only on that screen and then return to normal scanning without this option when the user leaves that screen.

That seems like a very reasonable thing to experiment with.
